# CSS3 Image sliding starting with invisible image

Tags: html, css

I have this code for my image to nicely slide in to my website from the right side.

```
img.move
{
position:relative
-webkit-animation-name: image;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes image {
0% {
right:-708px;
}
100% {
right: 0;
}
}
```

So right now in my webpage, this image starts in the right side background (it's gray) and ends up in its correct position in the container (it's white). 
What I want to do (but have no idea how to) is to make the image appear from thin air. What I mean is that it would still have its sliding animation, but it would be invisible on the gray part, and only appear out of white part, like the corner of container was printing it. So I wonder, is there any way I could do it?

Thanks for help

EDIT: JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/EpCM7/

Comment: Like on this website I am working on? http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/Benosh%20V2/index.html We also need your code to see what we are working with.

Comment: @user1477388 Created a JSfiddle

Comment: @ShidilDinesh I'm not sure how would that help. Yes - I want the image to be invisible at first, but I want it to be at 100% opacity. Lets say it like that - it all starts at 0% opacity, then during the animation, the part on the background is still 0%, and the part on the container is 100%, and at the end the whole part ends up being on container.

Comment: @JoshPowell - yes, the principle is the same! The only difference is that it's a single image.

Comment: I got this, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what I am doing is making the image a child of the `div.parent`.

Then I apply `overflow: hidden;` to the parent. When the image slides in from outside of it's parent it will not be visible due to the style.

The html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="move" src="http://vabankbroker.com/templates/vabankbroker/images/2.jpg" style="margin-right: -3px;" />
</div>
```

The css:

```
div.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The Fiddle: [JSFIDDLE, remove /show in url to view code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/EpCM7/6/show/)

**Better Practice**

```
@-webkit-keyframes image {
    0% {
        left: 100%; /* removes the use of negative values */
    }
    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. An interesting solution I'd have to say. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and best of luck! One last tip, to remove the use of negative values you can do `left: 100%;` on your key-frame for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

try adding opacity to the animation . might be the effect your looking for

```
@-webkit-keyframes image {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right:-708px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```